# How do I find active Bluemix users?

Tags: list, search, ibm-cloud

I have the internet address of a person and would like to find out whether this person is registered (and then active) in my Bluemix org.
Is there a function to do so?

Comment: is your requirement to do this programmatically?

Comment: No, it is a one-off query from time to time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage your account by clicking the 'user' icon on the top right of the Bluemix UI and then clicking on the [Manage Organizations](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/acctmgmt/index.html) option that will show you all the users that belong to your Bluemix Organization. You can also check the role that this user has. You can then click on the space name within your organization to see if that user has been given access to a space and what roles for that space.

Comment: Thank you, will try tomorrow (over midnight here).